# Get last changes of file with GIT

Tags: git

I have a project with some sql files with queries. Every developer increments the content of these files (they never remove content).

I need a git command to get all the new lines on all .sql files made by all developers from my last commit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to get the most recent revisions to a remote repository, you can use `git fetch`.

To see differences between your version and the most recent version, try `git diff`. To compare between a fetch and your version, try `git diff HEAD HEAD^`.

Comment: use `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` to see the changes in the other direction

Comment: Just clarifying, git diff HEAD^ HEAD shows changes you are pushing to the remote repository, changes you are making.

Answer (score 29):

`git whatchanged -p` or `git log -p` are probably what you want here. Either will show the diff-formatted changes introduced at each commit. There are additional options to limit the reporting to specific commits, or to specific files, or to format the output in different ways, see the respective manual pages for more information.

Comment: `git whatchanged` is similar to `git log` command and is kept for backward compatibility. New users are encouraged to use `git log` (source [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged)).